# IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, reflection

How is it possible that the "foo" exception is *not* thrown, but a subsequent call of invoke() throws the below exception?

```
if (method.getDeclaringClass() != object.getClass())
    throw new RuntimeException("foo");

method.invoke(object);
```

Thrown exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`

Comment: Can you give move details, for example the class definition?

Comment: more instead of move of course

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beh... The `method.invoke()` call wasn't the one throwing directly. The target method was using `invoke` too and it threw, so it bubbled up.

Lesson learned: Handle `InvocationTargetException` separately from other exceptions.

Comment: So: always look at the full stack trace.